# Текст на кнопке

Tags: css

Здравствуйте.
Есть текст на кнопке:

```
<button value='1' name='Sorted' onchange='this.form.submit();' style='font-size:9px; padding-left:-100px; text-align:left; width:150px;'>ожид.</button>
```

Вот хотел его `text-align:left`'ом пододвинуть к самому краю кнопки, не получается.
`div`'ом не желательно, так как передаю переменной `Sorted` значение `1`.

Возможно вообще такое реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
padding-left:0px;
text-align:left;
```

PS: отрицательный padding просто не обрабатывается и остается тем же.

Comment: Хм... а ведь в правильном направлении копал! Чуть-чуть не сообразил ведь :)
Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

`padding-left:-100px;` я таким образом текст по умолчанию с кнопки убираю, когда к ней бг изображение цепляю. В принципе, пикселями вымеряй, я думаю можно, как вариант, сделай картинку кнопки, текст куда хочешь и повесь её вместо стандартной)